# Defining injective functions in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, constraint-programming

My goal is to define an injective function `f: Int -> Term`, where `Term` is some new sort. Having referred to [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition) of the injective function, I wrote the following:

```
(declare-sort Term)
(declare-fun f (Int) Term)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int))
                (=> (= (f x) (f y)) (= x y))))
(check-sat)
```

This causes a timeout. I suspect that this is because the solver tries to validate the assertion for all values in the `Int` domain, which is infinite.

I also checked that the model described above works for some custom sort instead of `Int`:

```
(declare-sort Term)
(declare-sort A)
(declare-fun f (A) Term)
(assert (forall ((x A) (y A))
                (=> (= (f x) (f y)) (= x y))))
(declare-const x A)
(declare-const y A)
(assert (and (not (= x y)) (= (f x) (f y))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The first question is how to implement the same model for `Int` sort instead of `A`. Can solver do this?

I also found the injective function example in [the tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial) in multi-patterns section. I don't quite get why `:pattern` annotation is helpful. So the second question is why `:pattern` is used and what does it brings to this example particularly.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying this

```
(declare-sort Term)
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(declare-fun f (Int) Term)
(define-fun biyect () Bool
    (=> (= (f x) (f y)) (= x y)))
(assert (not biyect))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and I am obtaining this

```
sat 
(model 
  ;; universe for Term: 
  ;; Term!val!0 
  ;; ----------- 
  ;; definitions for universe elements: 
  (declare-fun Term!val!0 () Term) 
  ;; cardinality constraint: 
  (forall ((x Term)) (= x Term!val !0)) 
  ;; ----------- 
  (define-fun y () Int 
    1) 
  (define-fun x () Int 
    0) 
  (define-fun f ((x!1 Int)) Term 
    (ite (= x!1 0) Term!val!0 
    (ite (= x!1 1) Term!val!0 
      Term!val!0))) 
  )
```

Comment: This is not quite right. 1) You are declaring constants before defining the function and the function relies on specific constant values. As you can see in my second example, function is defined for all values in `A`. 2) The function `f` in your case is not an injective function. It can be seen from the model. For any input `x!1` it will produce the same answer `Term!val!0`. The function should produce the same answer **only** for the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this

```
(declare-sort Term)
(declare-fun f (Int) Term)
(define-fun biyect () Bool
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int))
            (=> (= (f x) (f y)) (= x y))))
(assert (not biyect))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and the output is

```
sat 
(model 
;; universe for Term: 
;; Term!val!0 
;; ----------- 
;; definitions for universe elements: 
(declare-fun Term!val!0 () Term) 
;; cardinality constraint: 
(forall ((x Term)) (= x Term!val!0))
;; ----------- 
(define-fun x!1 () Int 0)
(define-fun y!0 () Int 1) 
(define-fun f ((x!1 Int)) Term 
 (ite (= x!1 0) Term!val!0 
 (ite (= x!1 1) Term!val!0 
   Term!val!0))) 
)
```

Comment: This is similar to what I wrote. But why do you need `(assert (not biyect))` constraint here? Also `f` function still outputs the same value for two different values (0 and 1), so this is not an injective function, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes you are right, when you use (assert (not biyect)) Z3 produces an example of a function which is not injective. The point is that it is not possible to use Z3 with the aim to define an injective function at general.  Do you agreee?

Comment: At the moment I don't see any reason why it should be impossible. Also the injective function is provided in [the tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial). I am just trying to figure out is it possible to do for an infinite domain, like `Int`.